# PHP set cronjob for every 1 minutes

Tags: php, cron

First time I am setting up a cron job.
I have one simple PHP file. When this file is called it will insert one record in the database.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("cron_db") or die(mysql_error());
$tm = time();
$sql = "insert into test(time) values(".$tm.")";
if(mysql_query($sql))
{
    echo "done";
}
?>
```

I have uploaded this file to my server in **"public_html/dev/insert.php"**

For this i have written the below command

**`1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/domain/public_html/dev/insert.php`**

It isn't working. Can you help me to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked the error logs to see what the problem might be? What do you mean by "It isn't working."?

Comment: You know that the mysql_* functions are deprecated?

Comment: yes i know but it just peice of code -burzun

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/domain/public_html/dev/insert.php
```

will execute the cron job each first minute of an hour. What you want is:

```
*/1 * * * * www-data /usr/bin/php /home/domain/public_html/dev/insert.php
```

Note, that I've also inserted a column with the user which should execute the file (in this case, the webserver user. Could also be *root* or your username.)

Comment: it says crontab file cant install

Comment: hey.. i am getting this error now "/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: www-data: command not found"

Comment: Ok, then you're not editing an actual crontab, but something that generates it. Simply remove the `www-data` again, apparently that part is done by cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

What about piping the output of the cron to a "logfile" ?

Be sure of running the cron with the good user, having right permissions on the file

/home/domain/public_html/dev/insert.php > /home/domain/public_html/dev/insert.log

also check your php's cli php.ini settings & php error_logs